# Configuring GSA(Google Search Appliance) in ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-search-appliance

I am using GSA for my application.I want to display **promoted results** as part of my application.Can any one suggest me in which way i can use **OneBox**  for the getting promotted results.In which way i can configure it in **GSA Admin Console**?What type of results i will get on application from the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at keymatches? That's how you normally handle promoted results with the GSA.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. It helped. Thanks!